# MongoDB Aggregation : Rename a field in mongodb from ObjectId to literal/String?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a mongo collection which have fields `id`,`mobile` and `name` array.
Below is example of my collection,

```
        {
        "_id": 1,
        "mobile": "555-555-5555",
        "name": { "first" : ObjectId("1122334455") }
        }

        {
        "_id": 2,
        "mobile": "222-222-2222",
        "name": { "first" : ObjectId("5544332211") }
        }

        {
        "_id": 3,
        "mobile": "111-111-1111",
        "name": { "first" : ObjectId("1122334455")}
        }
```

I want to rename the `first` field in array `name` from `ObjectId` to `literal`
So my output will be something like this,

```
       {
        "_id": 1,
        "mobile": "555-555-5555",
        "name": { "first" : "Tom" }
        }

        {
        "_id": 2,
        "mobile": "222-222-2222",
        "name": { "first" : "abigail" }
        }

        {
        "_id": 3,
        "mobile": "111-111-1111",
        "name": { "first" : "Tom"}
        }
```

Comment: From where `Tom`, `abigail` came?

Comment: its a string to replace,
For  ObjectId("1122334455") - "Tom"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup`.  I assume that you have `user_source` collection that keeps your user details.

```
db.getCollection('Test01').aggregate(
[
    {
       $lookup:
       {
         from: "user_source",
         localField: "name.first",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "fromUsers"
       }
    },
    { $addFields : { "name.first":  {$arrayElemAt: [ "$fromUsers.name", 0 ]} } },
    { $project: { fromUsers: 0 } },
]
)
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace/rename the objectId with string.

Comment: you can use `$toString`

Comment: ```$toString``` will make ObjectId to string. Then can we replace string to another string.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html

Comment: Do you also want to get ObjectId value of the user as a string?

Comment: I need to replace the field ```first``` in name array to a custom string.

Comment: ObjectID is a reference key for the related user. You can not take the name with just convert it to a string.

Comment: Okay then I'll make a table for storing user details as recommended above.